# Time as a category list using GROUP BY - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, categories

I want to use `time` as a category and I have this tables:

Table **addonlist_final**

[image]

Table **addons**

[image]

I want the output to be look like this:

> **Order at 11:17 am**
>
> Coke 1 Litre
>
> Ham & Cheese Sandwich
>
> **Order at 11:15 am**
>
> Coke 1 Litre
>
> Hotdog Sandwich
>
> Tuna Sandwich

What I've currently done is this code, but only shows the first `item` on the group.

```
<?php

$getaddons = mysql_query("SELECT a.addon_id, a.description, a.price, a.status, fl.faddon_id, fl.quantity, fl.timef
                          FROM addons AS a
                          LEFT JOIN addonlist_final AS fl ON a.addon_id = fl.faddon_id AND fl.ftransac_id = '96675'
                          GROUP BY fl.timef
                          LIMIT 10
                          ");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getaddons)){
    $addonid = $rows['addon_id'];
    $addondesc = $rows['description'];
    $addonprice = $rows['price'];
    $addonstat = $rows['status'];
    $quantity = $rows['quantity'];
    $timef = $rows['timef'];
    $total = $addonprice * $quantity;

    if($rows['faddon_id']){
        echo "Ordered at $timef<br />";
        echo "$addondesc<br />";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}

?>
```

**Output:**

> **Ordered at 11:15 am**
>
> Coke 1 Litre
>
> **Ordered at 11:17 am**
>
> Coke 1 Litre

Comment: Instead of GROUP BY f1.timef, you could do ORDER BY f1.timef and just print out a line when the time has changed

Comment: SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42374e/1/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
<?php

include("conn.php");

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$time = date('h:i:s a', time());
$date = (date("D F d Y"));

echo $date." ".$time."<br /><br /><br />";

$getaddons = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, af.timef, af.quantity FROM addons AS a, addonlist_final AS af WHERE a.addon_id = af.faddon_id ORDER BY af.timef DESC");


$list = array();

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getaddons)){
    $timef = $rows['timef'];
    $list[$timef][] = $rows; 
}

foreach($list as $time => $group) {
  echo "Ordered at $time<br />";
  foreach($group as $rows) {
    $addonid = $rows['addon_id'];
    $addondesc = $rows['description'];
    $addonprice = $rows['price'];
    $addonstat = $rows['status'];
    $quantity = $rows['quantity'];
    $timef = $rows['timef'];
    $total = $addonprice * $quantity;

    if($rows['faddon_id']){
        echo "$addondesc<br />";
    }
  }
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Your SELECT Statement

```
SELECT ddonlist_final.faddon_id,addonlist_final.timef , addons.derscription
FROM addonlist_final
INNER JOIN addons
ON addonlist_final.faddon_id=addons.addon_id
ORDER BY addonlist_final.timef ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Then in PHP

```
$new_array = array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getaddons)){

  if($rows['faddon_id']){
      $new_array['timef'][] = $new_array['derscription'];
  }

}


   foreach($new_array as $time=>$addons){
       foreach($addons as $addon)
        echo "Ordered at $time<br />";
        echo "$addon<br />";
    }
```

Comment: ya I think this is the simplest way, I was typing out a similar answer

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to this:

```
SELECT a.faddonid, c.description, a.quantity, c.price, a.timef FROM addonlist_final a
INNER JOIN (SELECT timef FROM addonlist_final 
  WHERE  ftransac_id = '96675' GROUP BY timef) b
  ON a.timef = b.timef
INNER JOIN addons c
ON a.faddon_id = c.addon_id
WHERE a.ftransac_id = '96675'
```